# How to time Java program execution using Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, timing

- In Intellij IDEA it is possible to create run configurations. When I run a Java program and it completes execution then Intellij IDEA console shows something like this at the end

  > Process finished with exit code 0/1
- We have a unix command `time` which can be used for timing something. If I want to time a java command execution via command line then I can do something like

  > time java -version
- We have a option of adding external tools in Intellij's run configuration. By default it has `make` for compiling configured

Now I was thinking that I can possibly add the timing part to my run configurations. But the problem is that the external tools run before the actual execution.

I tried and added external tool `time` but it gave an error that no arguments were given.

Is it possible to wrap the java command's execution into the time like the example given above via Intellij's run configurations? Finally I want to time the java command's execution without changing the code itself. I am open to solutions other than linux `time` subject to they can be used with IDEA's run configurations.

Comment: Don't have a clue on how to do it in IntellJ (I'm an Eclipse guy), but is there a reason why you can't use 
`System.currentTimeMillis()` at the beggining and store it then subtract that from the time at the end of the code?

Comment: @AshwinGupta Basically because if I add it temporarily then will have to remember to remove that. I want to do it in my local and if this can be done via run configurations then I don't have to remember to remove that. I can just let it run always.

Comment: Okay I got you. Well in that case sorry, can't help you much since I use eclipse!

Comment: How about creating a "wrapper" program that times the execution of one of its calls? E.g. Instead of starting your program, you start the "timer" and then the timer calls the main method of your program?

Comment: @Olian04 Good try. But there are program arguments, VM arguments. I can copy paste them. But that takes me back to the issue of remembering to change one place when I change the other.